# Setting up an SSLContext using Spongy Castle

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle, spongycastle

How can I set up an SSLContext with TLS using Spongy Castle? I'm searching online but cannot find any good examples.

Comment: Bouncy Castle and by extension Spongy Castle doesn't come with a JSSE provider, so this doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to set up a TrustManager for passing into sslContext.init().  I'm calling TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(), "SC"), but Spongy Castle doesn't have any services of type "TrustManager".

Comment: So why are you using SC for this? Just use the platform one (no provider parameter).

Comment: I may plan on using parts of SC that are not included in Android's implementation of BC.

Comment: OK, so use them. But you cannot use something that is not there, i.e., JSSE, TrustManager, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot really be done, since Bouncy Castle and by extension Spongy Castle doesn't come with a JSSE provider. Use the platform default versions (don't specify a provider). When you need a specific algorithm that is not included in the system JCE providers, specify the SC provider explicitly.

Comment: I see; so if I understand correctly, neither Spongy Castle nor Bouncy Castle can be used as trust store providers when setting up an SSL/TLS connection?

Comment: Right. BTW, Spongy Castle is exactly the same as Bouncy Castle only with a different name so as not to clash with the one bundled in Android. Bouncy Castle does not offer a JSSE implementation, so you cannot use it for SSL. Details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html